# AWS Elastic Beanstalk necessary for Websites (vs. web apps)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The documentation only refers to web applications. Do I use the Elastic Beanstalk for my website or is it strictly for web apps? I've launched an EC2 instance that is not connected to the Elastic Beanstalk, however the default instance is running in the Elastic Beanstalk environment.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html

Comment: Yes, a website is a web app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk can be used for several type of applications:

1. Web App. Websites are included in "Web App" but it could be just a simple REST Api used by a mobile app and it would work as well.
2. Worker Application. Typically an application that would get message from a queue like SQS.

Elastic Beanstalk is a tool to help deployment of an entire infrastructure, from installing a webserver to deploy the code of the application and applying custom installation script. If you have a website using any technology supported by Elastic Beanstalk (Java, Node.js, PHP, Python, Ruby, and .NET) , I would definitely suggest that you use it as it is very simple to use and gives you a lot of advantages over a single ec2 instance.

You can read documentation for workers application here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

And I would suggest that you read the FAQ for more details:
http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/faqs/

As an example, in my company we set up beanstalk for more than 15 websites:  internal Backend tool in PHP, workers to send sms or emails, website with thousands of simultaneous users. One of the important point to mention is to be able to have a new website infrastructure up in about 20 minutes (new server with all configuration and code deployed).

Hope this helped you to understand Elastic Beanstalk. Don't hesitate to ask some more question and check Stackoverflow, there is a lot of information about it.